# How to split a string into arrays of different character using regex

Tags: javascript, regex, split

How do I split a string into different characters using regex in JS

For instance,

```
'aabbcdddaa'
```

would become

```
[aa, bb, c, dd, aa]
```

Appreciate any help, thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Capture a character and backreference.

```js
console.log('aabbcdddaa'.match(/(.)\1*/g));
```

Comment: May I know what does the '\1' means?

Comment: That's a backreference. Matches same character that was captured

Comment: I see, thanks mate!

Answer (score 0):

If you insist on using `split`, it is a bit more complicated, and only works on newer JavaScript engines (since it has to rely on lookbehind):

```js
console.log('aabbcdddaa'.split(/(?<=(.))(?!\1)/g).filter((e, i) => i % 2 == 0));
```

This captures a character in a lookbehind, then makes sure the lookahead character is different, thereby identifying the positions in the string where the two adjacent characters differ. However, using a capture inside `split` will insert the capture into the resultant list, so we need to filter out the unwanted "delimiters" by only keeping the even-numbered results.

NOTE: This answers the question literally as posted; in practice, using a global `match` as posted by Snow is vastly more readable, and also more performant (not to mention it will also work on older engines).

Comment: I am okay with match method. Thank you for your solution though!